# Laravel 8 Form Request Create vs Update

Tags: validación, laravel-8, formrequest

Buen día! Estimados colegas necesito de su ayuda, estoy trabajando con **Laravel8** tengo un **form request** que valida tanto el método **create** como **update**. En el caso de **create** todo funciona según lo esperado, por el contrario en el caso de **update** al intentar editar cualquier dato del formulario y realizar la validación me lo impide dado que el nombre de cliente ya existe. Por lo tanto las preguntas serian la siguientes: ¿Debo crear un **form request** para cada método? ¿Cual es la mejor practica recomendada? A su vez ¿Existe forma para el caso del **update** de especificar cotejar contra todos los clientes menos el que esta siendo editado?
Desde ya muchas gracias por la buena onda de siempre y el compartir conocimiento.
PD: Dejo algo de código y fotos para complementar lo expuesto.

**create**
[image: create form]
**update**
[image: edit form]

**form request**

````
```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class StoreCliente extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'nombre' => 'required|unique:clientes',
            'direccion' => 'required',
            'tipo_cliente_id' => 'required',
            'tel_fijo' => 'nullable|digits_between:10,15',
            'tel_fijo_alt' => 'nullable|digits_between:10,15',
            'cel' => 'nullable|digits_between:10,15',
            'cel_alt' => 'nullable|digits_between:10,15',
            'cp' => 'max:6',
            'email' => 'nullable|email',
            'email_alt' => 'nullable|email',
        ];
    }
    
    public function attributes()
    {
        return[
            
            'nombre'=>'nombre del cliente',
            'cp' => 'codigo postal',
            'tel_fijo' => 'telefono',
            'tel_fijo_alt' => 'telefono alternativo',
            'cel' => 'celular',
            'cel_alt' => 'celular alternativo',
            'email_alt' => 'email alternativo',
        ];
    }
    
    public function messages(){
        return [
            'nombre.required'=> 'Debe ingresar el nombre del cliente.'
        ];
    }
}```
````

**controller**

````
```<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\StoreCliente;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Cliente;
use App\Models\Domicilio;
use App\Models\TipoCliente;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;


class ClienteController extends Controller
{  

    public function index()
    {
        $clientes = Cliente::orderBy('nombre','asc')->get();
        $tipoclientes = TipoCliente::orderBy('categoria','asc')->get();
        return view('clientes.index', compact('clientes', 'tipoclientes'));
    }
    public function create()
    {
        $tipo_cliente = TipoCliente::pluck('categoria', 'id');
        return view('clientes.create', compact('tipo_cliente'));
    }
    // 
    public  function store(StoreCliente $request)
    {
        
        $cliente = Cliente::create($request->all());        
        return redirect()->route('clientes.show', $cliente)->with('estado','success');
    }

    public function show(Cliente $cliente)
    {
        
        return view('clientes.show', compact('cliente'));
    }

    public function edit(Cliente $cliente)
    {
        $tipo_cliente = TipoCliente::pluck('categoria', 'id');
        return view('clientes.edit', compact('cliente', 'tipo_cliente'));
    }

    public function update(StoreCliente $request, Cliente $cliente)
    {
        
        $cliente->update($request->all());        
        return redirect()->route('clientes.show', $cliente)->with('estado','update');
    }

    public function destroy(Cliente $cliente)
    {
        $cliente->delete();
        return redirect()->route('clientes.index');
    }
}
```
````

Answer (score 0):

No sé si ya obtuviste la manera de validar. Estoy trabajando en esto actualmente y me encontré con el mismo problema. La verdad es que tiene fácil solución, se trata de indicar que sea único, ignorándose a sí mismo, que es el caso del update:

'nombre' => [
'required',
Rule::unique('Clientes')->ignore($this->cliente),
]

Un saludo,